# How to use a map function with variables in racket (define)

Tags: racket

So I have a problem I'm trying to solve.

> Write a function called parity that takes four numbers, where each
> number is either 0 or 1, and produces another number that is either 0 or 1. Your function should produce 1 if there are an odd number
> of ones in the input numbers and 0 if there are an even number of ones.

I'm trying to do this in a roundabout way using the `map` function, currently sitting at

```racket
(define (parity a b c d)
  (map (lambda (thing)
         (positive? thing))
       '(a b c d)))
```

Then I would like to somehow create a new list using only the positive numbers, then find the length, then equate that to a `0` or a `1`. However, my code doesn't work after I define it due to the `positive?` searching for a number and finding an `a`.

Comment: The quoted list `'(a b c d)` is a list literal, so no matter what inputs `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` you provide, the lambda maps over the list `('a 'b 'c 'd)`. Instead, use `(list a b c d)` to create a list at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

First error is already mentioned in comments- instead of `'(a b c d)`, use `(list a b c d)` to get values of symbols.

There are two ways to get desired output and you don't need `map` in any of them:

- I can follow your process of thinking and use exactly these functions:

*create a new list using only the positive numbers* -> [`filter`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29)

*then find the length* -> [`length`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._length%29%29)

*then equate that to a 0 or a 1.* -> [`odd?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._odd%7E3f%29%29)/[`even?`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/number-types.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._even%7E3f%29%29) length or [`modulo`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._modulo%29%29)

```
(define (parity a b c d)
  (let* ((only-positive (filter positive? (list a b c d)))
        (len (length only-positive)))
    (if (odd? len) 1 0)))
```

This can be shortened to

```
(define (parity a b c d)
  (if (odd? (length (filter positive? (list a b c d)))) 1 0))
```

And note, that problem description almost exactly matches this solution: *if (odd (number of (ones in the input numbers))) 1 0*.

- Shorter solution with [`apply`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._apply%29%29):

```
(define (parity a b c d)
  (modulo (apply + (list a b c d)) 2))
```